# getting sum of a column from the last 30 days in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Im working with Opencart and am a little leary when it comes to this stuff. I have this mysql query that works fine but now I need another one that shows this information from the last 30 days. The two columns from the table are amount, date_added How do I add the 30 day check to this query? I know I need to include the date_added column to the query but not sure how.

```
 public function getSum() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate");            
           return $query->row; 
    }
```

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause that tests whether the date is in the desired time period. What's the problem?

Comment: @adamg You need to include Where condition in your queryyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (depends on the used data type):

```
"SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate WHERE date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)"
```